# How to get notified when a tableViewController finishes animating the push onto a nav stack

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm pushing a `UITableViewController` onto a `UINavigationController` with `pushViewController:animated:`.  I'd like to be notified the moment the animation finishes so I can use `selectRowAtIndexPath` to scroll to and highlight a given row.
How can I set the delegate of an animation I didn't call explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to set the delegate of the push animation. Here's a simple workaround:

Subclass `UITableViewController`. Override `viewDidAppear:` to call your "post-animation" method after a short delay.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToAndHighlightCurrentRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
}
```

Comment: Oh great.  So `viewDidAppear` is only called once that push animation is completed?  Perfect, That did it. Thanks.

Comment: The `viewDidAppear:` method is also called when a hidden view has its obstructions removed. For example, if you push another view on top of your table view, when you pop that view, the `viewDidAppear:` method of your table view controller will be called again.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356256/how-to-get-notified-when-scrolltorowatindexpath-finishes-animating for a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply calling the selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: method (via the tableView property) before you push it onto the navigation controller's stack?

Comment: Yes. That's what I do know, but then the scroll animation finishes at the same time or before the push animation.  I want the user to know they're being scrolled to a certain row, by only starting the scroll (and highlight) animation once the push animation has finished.