# Best way to make offscreen table cell subviews available for makeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a table view based on a feed that contains what is essentially a number of form type elements.  Simplified think of it as containing two types of elements textboxes and messages. Textbox type cells should contain UITextFields and Message type cells contain a non editable UITextArea.

I have created a custom cell to handle each of the types and render them into a table. So far so good.

The client has requested a prev/next/done inputAccessoryView like the one that safari uses for html forms.  A bit of work later I've got that up and running, I add some functionality that makes prev/next skip over message type cells and only call makeFirstResponder when it finds a textbox type cell.  Still things seem to be going smoothly.

Then I added, in testing, a really long message to test my row height setting code.  When I try to prev or next over this message cell it fails with a:

```
2012-02-21 11:34:36.642 MobileMarketing[52410:13a03] -[ContactFormTableViewController selectUpdate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89802f0
2012-02-21 11:34:36.643 MobileMarketing[52410:13a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ContactFormTableViewController selectUpdate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89802f0'
```

I assume this is because the target field on the far side of the message and now offscreen has been dequeued. I'm reading up on that.  But a long way around for a simple question.  Does anyone have a good technique for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you may be able to solve this using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` as seen here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

If you scroll to the next cell, you can guarantee it exists before you try to makeFirstResponder.

Comment: I was just trying the same big and still when I grab the cell it's not there (yet).  I assume there is an event to hook when the scrolling is done, however.

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` ought to take care of that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356256/how-to-get-notified-when-scrolltorowatindexpath-finishes-animating

Comment: An unrelated bug was sending me into the weeds but this did solve my problem.  As an aside an added wrinkle if scrollToRowAtIndexPath: does not cause actual scrolling then scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: never gets called.