# How to execute code after an animation without using the completion block?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation, uiscrollview

I would like to execute some code after a built-in animation is completed.

I have a UITableView with a lot of cells/rows. Sometimes, when I do some operations and then I need to scroll to the top of my tableView. For that I use :

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

But I need to perform some code once the top is reached, such a simple select and deselect of the 1rst row.

I implemented `func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView)` from the `UIScrollViewDelegate`. It works fine (more or less, sometimes the animation isn't really smooth and we don't see the select/deselect "animation") except when I am already at the top of the tableView, then `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` isn't called.

So is there a way to execute some code once `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` has been called?

**EDIT:**

When I'm talking about doing some operations, I'm talking about moving a row using `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath` from `UITableView`.

So when scrolling is needed it's fine, both animations take about the same amount of time. But when no scroll is needed, then the execution of the code I want to do after the animation, starts at the same time than the animation

Comment: Have you tried putting your post animation code into scrollViewDidEndDragging() and/or scrollViewDidEndDecelerating() ?

Comment: Yes I tried them both and they aren't called in my case as it an animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this Swift code which I adapted from [an old Objective-C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14372218/2446155) to scroll the view.

```
// First, test whether the tableView needs to scroll to the new position
var originalOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y;
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)

var offset = tableView.contentOffset.y;

if (originalOffset == offset) {
    // No animation is needed since its already there
    doThingAfterAnimation();
} else {
    // We know it will scroll to a new position
    // Return to originalOffset. animated:NO is important
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, originalOffset), animated: false);
    // Do the scroll with animation so `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` will execute
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
}
```

And then of course:

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    doThingAfterAnimation();
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to add some more information which makes more sense regarding the title of my question. In this case, the need for scrolling is well detected but when I don't have to scroll, the `doThingAfterAnimation` starts at the same time that the animation moving my row while I'm looking for it to start once the animation is done.

Comment: If you are _also_ trying to move cells around at the same time, then you would need to add a completion block for those animations using one of the methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832474/uitableview-row-animation-duration-and-completion-callback), and making sure that both the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` func _and_ your completion block for your cell movement animations had been called before continuing on to `doThingAfterAnimation`. I _think_ they are always the same animation duration, so you might not need to coordinate them too much...